# How to merge Strings and Integers together with PHP?

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I'm trying to merge some integers and strings together and output them with echo.

What I've done:

```
$a=1
$b=2
$c=3
$d=4

echo 'var saveName = "' . $a . '_KID=' . $b . '_RID=' . $c . '";var RID = ' . $d . ';';
```

however that throws an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$b' (T_VARIABLE) in ...

I don't see whats wrong here. What causes that error?

Comment: $a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;

Comment: [See this page in the PHP manual's basic syntax section.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing semicolons:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of missing semicolons in your variable declarations, not invalid string merging. Have in mind that php **does** require programmer to [end instructions with semicolons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your are missing the semicolons at the end of every instructions.

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;
$d = 4;

echo "var saveName = \"{$a}_KID={$b}_RID={$c}\";var RID = {$d};";
```

You should use a proper editor that lints the code, or even something like [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/to4vk) that show your errors.

Also, you can use string interpolation with echo, that is slightly faster than concatenation, especially in PHP7, and also easier to read.